# Regular expression with positive lookbehind at beginning fails to match whole string

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

I am using Python with the `re` module and trying to match strings like `decimal(4,1)` and `decimal(10,5)`, while only actually returning the `4,1` and `10,5`, with the following regular expression:

```
(?<=decimal\()\d+,\d+(?=\)$)
```

Let's say I compile the regex with `re.compile` and name it `DECIMAL`. If I try to search `decimal(4,1)` for instances of the regex like so:

```
DECIMAL = re.compile(r'(?<=decimal\()\d+,\d+(?=\)$)')
results = DECIMAL.search('decimal(4,1)')
```

`results.group(0)` returns the string `4,1` as desired. However, if I try to match rather than search:

```
results = DECIMAL.match('decimal(4,1)')
```

`results` evaluates to `None`.

Does the `match` method fail here because `match` looks to fully match the consuming part of the regex against the beginning of the haystack and thus doesn't have any room for a preceding positive-length pattern to confirm?

As for the immediately practical, simply searching won't work in this case, since `DECIMAL` would turn up results in unacceptable strings like `snarfdecimal(4,1)`. Should I be dropping in a beginning-of-string token somewhere, or is there something else I'm missing entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to use a positive look-behind at all,

```
>>> import re
>>> find_decimal = re.compile(r'decimal\((\d+,\d+)\)')
>>> find_decimal.match('decimal(4,1)').group(1)
'4,1'
```

As for the reason it doesn't work, not sure but I'd guess you are correct in your thinking.

Comment: This will only match instances at the beginning of the input string. What about using re.search and adding some \b characters?

Comment: @CharlesMarsh He wants to use `match` over `search`.

Comment: I don't think he has an inherent bias towards `match` over `search`. He just want to avoid matching things like `snarfdecimal(4,1)`, which can still be achieved with `search` by using \b characters. Anyway, just a suggestion. Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `search()`, Python's `match()` method automatically anchors the match at the beginning of the string.  That means you're trying to match the literal string `decimal(` *before* the beginning of the string, which of course will always fail.

But [as Jared pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18069711/20938), you don't need lookbehind for this anyway.  In fact, lookbehind should be the *last* tool you reach for, not the first.

Here's a slightly modified version of Jared's regex:

```
r'\bdecimal\(\s*(\d+\s*,\s*\d+)\s*\)'
```

The most important change is the addition of the word boundary (`\b`) to prevent it matching things like `snarfdecimal(4,1)`.  If you really have to use `match()` instead of `search()`, you can "pad" the regex with `.*?`, forcing it to consume the intermediate characters:

```
r'.*?\bdecimal\(\s*(\d+\s*,\s*\d+)\s*\)'
```